# Inverting chained maps?

Tags: ocaml

A very common pattern in functional programming is to chain a series of calls to `map` on lists. A contrived, simple example:

```
[1; 2; 3] |> List.map (fun x -> x + 1) |> List.map (fun x -> x * 2)
```

Where the result is:

```
[4; 6; 8]
```

Now it's easy enough to flip this on its head and avoid the creation of lists at each stage, *if* the types never change: simply have `map` take a list of functions to apply in order:

```ml
let list_map_chained : 'a. ('a -> 'a) list -> 'a list -> 'a list =
  let rec apply x chain =
    begin match chain with
    | []          -> x
    | f :: chain' -> apply (x |> f) chain'
    end
  in
  fun chain xs ->
    List.map (fun x -> apply x chain) xs
```

Which we can use like this:

```ml
[1; 2; 3] |> list_map_chained [ (fun x -> x + 1) ; (fun x -> 2 * x) ]
```

But if we want to do the same thing to a sequence like the following:

```
[1; 2; 3] |> List.map (fun x -> x + 1) 
          |> List.map (fun x -> x * 2)
          |> List.map (fun x -> float_of_int x /. 3.)
```

Now the types do change, but because of the heterogenous nature of the types, the functions cannot be stored in anything like a list that expects (and requires) homogenous types. Obviously this is very straightforward in a less strictly typed programming language like Ruby:

```rb
class Array
  def inverted_map(*lambdas)
    self.map { |x| lambdas.inject(x) { |sum, l| l.call(sum) } }
  end
end

irb(main):032:0> [1,2,3].inverted_map(lambda { |x| x + 1 }, lambda { |x| x * 2 }, lambda { |x| x.to_f / 3})
=> [1.3333333333333333, 2.0, 2.6666666666666665]
```

I know a fair amount about Ocaml, but I am open to not knowing it all. Is there a way to accomplish this within Ocaml's type system that is not more trouble than it's worth?

Comment: And now if I put that expression in `toplevel`, it produces...

[1; 2; 3] |> List.map (fun x -> x + 1) 
          |> List.map (fun x -> x * 2)
            |> List.map (fun x -> float_of_int x /. 3.);;


- : float list = [1.33333333333333326; 2.; 2.66666666666666652]

Comment: Which is expected. I'm seeking a means of applying a (variable arity) series of functions which may not all have the same type to a list of values, thus avoiding the creation of a new list at each stage in the process. Of course, this trivial example I could also simply write: `[1; 2; 3] |> List.map (fun x -> float_of_int ((x + 1) * 2) /. 3.)`, but that wouldn't be challenging, and thus _no fun_.

Comment: You could probably use [difflists](https://drup.github.io/2016/08/02/difflists/).

Comment: Thanks @glennsl. A good read for when I'm awake enough to type `;` instead of `,`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### By composing functions

Instead of actually storing the sequence of functions to apply successively, why not compose them right ahead?

```ml
(* (0) ORIGINAL CODE: *)

let () =
  [1; 2; 3]
  |> List.map (fun x -> x + 1)
  |> List.map (fun x -> float x /. 3.)
  |> List.map string_of_float
  |> List.iter print_endline

(* (1) BY COMPOSING FUNCTIONS: *)

let (%>) f g x = x |> f |> g

let () =
  [1; 2; 3]
  |> List.map (
      (fun x -> x + 1) %>
      (fun x -> float x /. 3.) %>
      string_of_float
    )
  |> List.iter print_endline
```

### Storing a heterogeneous list of (chained) functions with a GADT

Now I don’t think there is any reason to do it, but if you *actually* want what you said in your question, you can achieve it with a GADT. I think this is what @glennsl was suggesting in a comment when mentioning “[difflists](https://drup.github.io/2016/08/02/difflists/)”.

In the code below, we define a new inductive type `(a, c) fun_chain` for function chains whose composed type is `a -> c`; in other words, for heterogeneous lists of functions `[f0; f1; …; fn]` whose types are as follows:

```
f0 :     a -> b1
f1 :          b1 -> b2
…                      …
f{n-1} :                 b{n-1} -> bn
fn :                               bn -> c
```

As the `b1, …, bn` do not appear in the final type, they are existentially quantified, and so is `'b` in the type of the `(::)` constructor.

```ml
(* (2) WITH A GADT: *)

(* Syntax tip: we overload the list notation [x1 ; … ; xn],
 * but wrap our notation in a module to help disambiguation. *)
module Chain = struct

  type (_, _) fun_chain =
    |  []  : ('a, 'a) fun_chain
    | (::) : ('a -> 'b) * ('b, 'c) fun_chain -> ('a, 'c) fun_chain

  (* [reduce] reduces a chain to just one function by composing all
   * functions of the chain. *)
  let rec reduce : type a c. (a, c) fun_chain -> a -> c =
    fun chain ->
      begin match chain with
      | []          -> fun x -> x
      | f :: chain' -> f %> reduce chain'
      end

  (* [map] is most easily implemented by first reducing the chain... *)
  let map : type a c. (a, c) fun_chain -> a list -> c list =
    fun chain ->
      List.map (reduce chain),
  (* ... but then it’s just a more convoluted way of pre-composing functions,
   * as in suggestion (1). If you don’t want to do that,
   * you would reimplement [map] with nested loops
   * (the outer loop goes through the list of pre-images,
   * the inner loop applies each function in turn).
   * But it is equivalent both from a high-level algorithmic perspective,
   * and at the low-level memory representation,
   * so I only expect a negligible performance difference. *)

end

let () =
  [1; 2; 3]
  |> Chain.map [
      (fun x -> x + 1) ;
      (fun x -> 2 * x) ;
      (fun x -> float x /. 3.) ;
      string_of_float
    ]
  |> List.iter print_endline
```

#### A note on polymorphic type annotations

In the code above, you might be intrigued by the type annotations on the definition of `reduce` and `map` (for `map` it is not actually needed, but I like to make sure we have the intended type).

Briefly, [`: type a. …` is a type annotation with explicit (forced) polymorphism](https://ocaml.org/manual/locallyabstract.html#p:polymorpic-locally-abstract). You can think of this as the universal quantifier: ∀ *a*, … or as a binder for a type-level argument. In the code above we make use of advanced features of the type system, namely, [polymorphic recursion](https://ocaml.org/manual/polymorphism.html#s:polymorphic-recursion) and [branches with different types](https://ocaml.org/manual/gadts.html), and that leaves type inference at a loss. In order to have a program typecheck in such a situation, we need to force polymorphism like this.

For a more lengthy explanation, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69144536).

Comment: The syntax trick (overloading the list notation) is independent from the problem at hand. To make things conceptually simpler, you can rename the fancy `[]` and `::` constructors into something more regular such as `Nil` and `Cons`, and then the heterogeneous list of functions `[f1; f2; f3]` would rather be written as `Cons (f1, Cons (f2, Cons (f3, Nil)))`.

Comment: @Maëlan, very nice explanation.. the only thing which I couldn't get my head around is...
: type a c. (a, c) fun_chain -> a ->c.... Is it something like `type`-brother of `lambda` the function ? Still lot to discover, but do you have any thing which I can follow and understand? Quick links, books, articles, anything...

Comment: You’re right asking about that, I left it unexplained. I just added some explanations but that ended up pretty lengthy and off-topic, so I think I should move it to a separate question, Q&A style.