# What type annations can I use to allow different calls to a function to assume different polymoprhic types

Tags: polymorphism, ocaml

This question is connected to another question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72065580/what-is-the-difference-meaning-of-type-a-versus-type-a).

But this question is a bit more focused on this simple piece of code that I wrote in trying to understand the different type annotations like `(type a):`  versus `: type a.`.

```
let f = fun id x -> 
    let i = id 4 in
    let f = id 4.0 in
       (Int.to_float i) +. f;;
```

This code doesn't type check. I understand that is because the checker 'infers' `id : int -> ...` from `let i = id 4` but that conflicts with inferring `id : float -> ...` on next line.

Intuitively though I would expect the above code to be 'fine' if we can somehow tell the type system that the function `id` is of type `a -> a` and this type is allowed to vary between call sites. (i.e. we can pick a different `'a` on every call to `id`).

I gather that annotations like `type a.` and `(type a) :` are there precisely to let me tell that to the type checker somehow.

Here's one of the things I tried. I annotated the 'binding occurrence' of `id` to use `type a.` to try and make it 'explicitly polymorphic'. But the syntax won't let me actually use `type a. ...` there as a type annotation.

```
let f = fun (id : type a.a -> a) x -> begin 
               (* ^^^^ syntax error: type expected *) 
         let i = id 4 in
         let f = id 4.0 in
         (Int.to_float i) +. f
end;;
```

A bit confusing/ironic that error. It points at the word 'type' and says that what is expected there is `type`. I gather the error means it expects 'a type' rather than the keyword `type`. However I thought (mistakenly I guess) that `type a. ...` would actually considered as a valid 'type'.

So, finally the question is there *some* way to annotate my piece of code and make it type check? Or is it not possible?

Comment: It's a minor note, but the `begin` and `end` are extraneous in the code you've shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underlying problem here is that this requires higher-rank polymorphism, which OCaml does not support implicitly. The workaround is to make it explicit by wrapping the function in a record or object, which allows for universal quantification on a field or method level.

```
type f = { f: 'a. 'a -> 'a }

let f = fun id ->
   let i = id.f 4 in
   let f = id.f 4.0 in
   float_of_int i +. f
```

See the section on [Polymorphism and its limitations](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/polymorphism.html#s:higher-rank-poly) in the OCaml manual for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I would accept/upvote this answer, but I think I just don't understand this type-system stuff enough to know whether this answer is correct. I am not saying it is incorrect. Just that I don't know enough to determine that. (And we all know proving something is 'impossible' is much harder than just showing a way that it is possible). So I'll wait a bit and see if some other answers appear.

Comment: No worries. I'm just parroting the manual section I'm linking to though, which shows an example that is very close to yours, explaining that it's not possible, and the same workaround (as well as one that uses objects instead of records).

Comment: ok, so I took some time to digest that piece of manual, and I think you are right it looks like a very similar situation and they do say that you can only do it via record or object method workaround. So accepting this. TBH. I didn't expect the answer to be 'it is impossible'. That just shows you I still don't understand these `type a.` and `(type a) :` notations. Since I really thought the point of them was exactly to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: Adding some nuance, OCaml does support a form higher-rank polymorphism, after all the code proposed is working. However, this support is limited to a very explicit form of higher-rank polymorphism that need to go through polymorphic record fields or methods because this way avoids all the issue involved with implicit higher-rank polymorphism.