# Why Peano numbers in OCaml not working due to scope error?

Tags: ocaml, gadt, peano-numbers

I have the following peano number written with GADTs:

```ml
type z = Z of z

type 'a s = Z | S of 'a

type _ t = Z : z t | S : 'n t -> 'n s t

module T = struct
  type nonrec 'a t = 'a t
end

type 'a nat = 'a t

type e = T : 'n nat -> e
```

The following function to decode a `'a nat` (or `'a t`) into the number it encoded, works:

```ml
let to_int : type n. n t -> int =
  let rec go : type n. int -> n t -> int =
   fun acc n -> match n with Z -> acc | S n -> go (acc + 1) n
  in
  fun x -> go 0 x
```

but if I try to rewrite it almost exactly the same this way:

```ml
let to_int2 (type a) (a: a nat) : int =
  let rec go (type a) (acc : int) (x : a nat) : int =
    match x with
    | Z -> acc
    | S v -> go (acc + 1) v
  in
  go 0 a
```

I get a scope error. What's the difference between the two functions?

```
138 |     | S v -> go (acc + 1) v
                                ^
Error: This expression has type $0 t but an expression was expected of type
         'a
       The type constructor $0 would escape its scope
```

Comment: What makes you think it's "almost exactly the same"? One is explicitly polymorphic, the other is not. That's quite a big difference. See https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/locallyabstract.html#p:polymorpic-locally-abstract

Comment: I guess there's something fundamental that's happening here that I don't get, because I don't see the difference between the two implementations. But I know there's one (otherwise I wouldn't get the error)

Comment: oh I think I see it, `type x .` is different than `(type x)`. Weirdly in utop I do get the same function signature if I write `let thing (type a) (a:a) : unit = ()` and `let thing : 'a . 'a -> unit = fun a -> ()`

Comment: Might be because it only matters for polymorphic recursion, i.e. how the function sees itself. I'm not very familiar with how `utop` works.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69144536/in-ocaml-what-is-the-difference-between-a-and-type-a-and-when-to-use-eac

Comment: The accepted answer points to a post that explains that eventhough the two signatures are the same, they are typechecked differently! How can you know this without knowing deep detail of how the compiler works :( I fee betrayed

Comment: There is no need to know the compiler internals: the let-polymorphism restriction that forbids polymorphic recursion is part of the (fully formalized) core ML type system. Going further, the OCaml extension that allows for polymorphic recursion has its section in the OCaml manual.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The root issue is polymorphic recursion, GADTs are a red herring here.

Without an explicit annotation, recursive functions are not polymorphic in their own definition.
For instance, the following function has type `int -> int`

```ml
let rec id x =
   let _discard = lazy (id 0) in
   x;;
```

because `id` is not polymorphic in

```ml
   let _discard = lazy (id 0) in
```

and thus `id 0` implies that the type of `id` is `int -> 'a`  which leads to `id` having type `int -> int`.
In order to define polymorphic recursive function, one need to add an explicit universally quantified annotation

```ml
let rec id : 'a. 'a -> 'a = fun x ->
  let _discard = lazy (id 0) in
  x
```

With this change, `id` recovers its expected `'a -> 'a` type.
This requirement does not change with GADTs. Simplifying your code

```
let rec to_int (type a) (x : a nat) : int =
    match x with
    | Z -> 0
    | S v ->  1 + to_int v
```

the annotation `x: a nat` implies that the function `to_int` only works with  `a nat`, but you are applying to an incompatible type (and ones that lives in a too narrow scope but that is secondary).

Like in the non-GADT case, the solution is to add an explicit polymorphic annotation:

```ml
let rec to_int: 'a. 'a nat -> int = fun (type a) (x : a nat) ->
    match x with
    | Z -> 0
    | S v ->  1 + to_int v
```

Since the form  `'a. 'a nat -> int = fun (type a) (x : a nat) ->`  is both a mouthful and quite often needed with recursive function on GADTs, there is a shortcut notation available:

```ml
let rec to_int: type a. a nat -> int = fun x ->
    match x with
    | Z -> 0
    | S v ->  1 + to_int v
```

For people not very familiar with GADTs, this form is the one to prefer whenever one write a GADT function. Indeed, not only this avoids the issue with polymorphic recursion, writing down the explicit type of a function before trying to implement it is generally a good idea with GADTs.

See also https://ocaml.org/manual/polymorphism.html#s:polymorphic-recursion , https://ocaml.org/manual/gadts-tutorial.html#s%3Agadts-recfun , and https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/locallyabstract.html#p:polymorpic-locally-abstract .